# How to declare runtime api?

Tags: rust, substrate-node, runtime-api

I have a runtime constant declared in a pallet like this:

```rust
        /// How much space there is on the network.
        #[pallet::constant]
        type TotalSpacePledged: Get<u128>;
```

[Source code](https://github.com/subspace/subspace/blob/5d8b65740ff054b01ebcbaf5a905e74274c1a5d0/crates/pallet-transaction-fees/src/lib.rs#L87-L90)

And it is defined like in the runtime like this:

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub CreditSupply: Balance = Balances::total_issuance();
    pub TotalSpacePledged: u128 = {
        let sectors = solution_range_to_sectors(Subspace::solution_ranges().current);
        sectors as u128 * MAX_PIECES_IN_SECTOR as u128 * Piece::SIZE as u128
    };
    pub BlockchainHistorySize: u128 = u128::from(Subspace::archived_history_size());
    pub DynamicCostOfStorage: bool = RuntimeConfigs::enable_dynamic_cost_of_storage();
}

impl pallet_transaction_fees::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type TotalSpacePledged = TotalSpacePledged;
    ...
}
```

Now, if I want to access the value using runtime_api as I have a full node running, I wrote the code like this:

```rust
sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
    pub trait TotalSpacePledgedApi {
        fn get_total_space_pledged() -> u128;
    }
}

impl TotalSpacePledgedApi<Block> for Runtime {
    fn get_total_space_pledged(&self) -> u128 {
        self::TotalSpacePledged::get()
    }

    #[doc = r" !!INTERNAL USE ONLY!!"]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    fn __runtime_api_internal_call_api_at(
        &self,
        at: <Block as sp_api::__private::BlockT>::Hash,
        params: std::vec::Vec<u8>,
        fn_name: &dyn Fn(sp_api::__private::RuntimeVersion) -> &'static str,
    ) -> std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<u8>, sp_api::__private::ApiError> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/subspace/subspace/blob/f79f225b799f16c2a9efe41123a8c75307e50456/crates/subspace-runtime/src/lib.rs#L434-L456)

This throws error:

```sh
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: sp_api::Core<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>, CheckStorageAccess, DisablePallets)>>>` is not satisfied
   --> crates/subspace-runtime/src/lib.rs:440:38
    |
440 | impl TotalSpacePledgedApi<Block> for Runtime {
    |                                      ^^^^^^^ the trait `sp_api::Core<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>, CheckStorageAccess, DisablePallets)>>>` is not implemented for `Runtime`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `sp_api::Core<Block>`:
              <domain_block_preprocessor::stateless_runtime::StatelessRuntime<Block, Executor> as sp_api::Core<Block>>
              <RuntimeApiImpl<__SrApiBlock__, RuntimeApiImplCall> as sp_api::Core<__SrApiBlock__>>
note: required by a bound in `TotalSpacePledgedApi`
   --> crates/subspace-runtime/src/lib.rs:434:1
    |
434 | / sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
435 | |     pub trait TotalSpacePledgedApi {
436 | |         fn get_total_space_pledged() -> u128;
437 | |     }
438 | | }
    | |_^ required by this bound in `TotalSpacePledgedApi`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `sp_api::decl_runtime_apis` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0050]: method `get_total_space_pledged` has 1 parameter but the declaration in trait `TotalSpacePledgedApi::get_total_space_pledged` has 2
   --> crates/subspace-runtime/src/lib.rs:441:32
    |
434 | / sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
435 | |     pub trait TotalSpacePledgedApi {
436 | |         fn get_total_space_pledged() -> u128;
437 | |     }
438 | | }
    | |_- trait requires 2 parameters
...
441 |       fn get_total_space_pledged(&self) -> u128 {
    |                                  ^^^^^ expected 2 parameters, found 1
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me here .

Comment: `TotalSpacePledged` does not need a runtime API to be exposed. You can query it in PolkadotJS developer->chainstate->constants https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate/constants

Comment: But, I need to access this via.....`client.runtime_api().total_space_pledged()`.

Comment: Ah okay. Was not sure what you were trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly implemented.

The correct implementation [commit](https://github.com/subspace/subspace/commit/df8d33b65fff6a88d77fa8090533879199bcb422).

Basically, inside the pallet, the declaration has to be happen. And in the runtime, implementation has to be done.